# Sampling a large number of rows from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I want to extract a **roughly** 5 million row sample from a table that will contain somewhere between 10 million and 20 million rows.

Due to the large number of rows, efficiency is key. As such, I am trying to avoid sorting the rows where possible, hence why I am avoiding the dbms_random.value solution that I have seen in similar questions.

I tried to do something like the following:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      full_table
SAMPLE    (CEIL(100 * 5000000 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM full_table)));
```

However, I can't seem to do arithmetic in the SAMPLE clause (ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended - I tried this with a simple SAMPLE(10/2) and still get the same thing).

Is this a reasonable approach, and, if so, how do I calculate the number of rows in the sample clause?

Comment: If this is a one-off exercise, why not just count the rows, figure out the percentage, and hard-code it into your SAMPLE clause?  If you would really be doing this many times and need to fine-tune the percentage each time, use dynamic SQL.

Comment: That would be great, but this is being developed against a test database, and I don't have access to the production environment. To clarify though, it will be a one-off.

Comment: Which client will it be run in - if SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer you could just use a substitution variable? Other clients may have something similar. Or would the `ora_hash` method [shown here](https://blogs.oracle.com/datamining/entry/to_sample_or_not_to_sample) be efficient enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use PL/SQL with dynamic SQL like this:

```
declare
  cnt integer;
begin
  select count(*) into cnt from full_table;
  dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
  execute immediate
    'insert into target_table'
    ||' select * from full_tablesample (' || ceil(100 * 5000000/cnt) || ')';
end;
```

Comment: I'll upvote.  But, for even more efficiency, consider replacing the `SELECT COUNT(*)...` with `select count(*)*10000 from full_table sample (0.01)`.  Since we're dealing with rough numbers, that may be close enough and a lot faster.

Comment: Good idea @MatthewMcPeak!

Answer (score 2):

If you need *roughly* 5 million rows, you can do:

```
SELECT ft.*
FROM full_table ft cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM full_table) x
WHERE dbms_random.value * cnt < 5000000;
```

This uses simple arithmetic to determine which rows go into the table.  The result should be pretty close to 5,000,000.

Comment: Why would this draw a downvote?  It seems like a correct answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps it was because it uses dbms_random.value, which OP mentioned wanting to avoid.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, The way I read OP, `dbms_random` is not the problem, but that the solutions OP has seen are doing an `order by dbms_random.value` then selecting the top x rows. That is the problem. This solution avoids the cost of an order by, but introduces inexactness in the number of rows returned, but will be roughly 5e6.

Comment: @TonyAndrews . . . You are taking that out of context:  "I am trying to avoid sorting the rows where possible, hence why I am avoiding the dbms_random.value solution".  This does not sort the rows.  It uses the random value in a more appropriate way.  And, I should add, the OP is asking for *roughly* 5,000,000 rows, which is what this does.

Comment: This is a pretty neat solution as there's no need for PL/SQL. Thanks @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right - but that still but explain someone's misguided motivation for the downvote, which is what I was trying to guess.